# Theorem on formal functions when the initial data is a proper map of formal schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, arithmetic-geometry, rigid-analytic-geometry, formal-schemes

Let $\pi: X \to S:=\mathrm{Spf}\text{ } A$ be a proper morphism of $\mathbb{Z}_p$-admissible formal schemes and $\mathcal{F}$ be a coherent sheaf on $X$.

Set $S_0=\{x\}$ be a closed point of $S$ and $X_0=\pi^{-1}(x)$. Is there any analogous result to '' the Theorem on formal functions '' in this setting  ? i.e., an isomorphism
$R^i \pi_{*} (\mathcal{F})^{\wedge } \simeq R^i \widehat{\pi_{*}} (\widehat{\mathcal{F}})$, where

1. $R^i \pi_{*} (\mathcal{F})^{\wedge }$ is the completion of $R^i \pi_{*} (\mathcal{F})$ at $S_0=\{x\}$.
2. $\widehat{\pi}: \widehat{X}^{X_0} \to \widehat{S}^{S_0}$ is the completion of $\pi$.
3. $\widehat{\mathcal{F}}$ is the complétion of $\mathcal{F}$ along $X_0$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0A0G seems very general. https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0A0H is explaining how to use this general version to deduce the classical. Maybe the ideas apply.

Comment: Thank you for the reference !